# Текст из EditText в поле inputText webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview, input

Как передать текст из *EditText* в поле *inputText* *webview* после загрузки страницы, а также нажать на кнопку на сайте программно?

Пробую вставить текст таким образом в методе `onFinised`:

```
String txtLogin = eTxtLogin.getText().toString();
webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('email').value="+txtLogin);
```

Но он не срабатывает.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте написать так:

```
String txtLogin = eTxtLogin.getText().toString();
webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('email').value=" + txtLogin);
```

Comment: я так и делал, опечатался в вопросе, но все-равно ничего

Comment: Для получения правильного ответа рекомендую прислать полный текст метода или класса. По 2-м строчкам иногда сложно ответить адекватно!